# Is there a reference/list of standard LaTeX terminology?

Tags: syntax, naming, grammar

I'm writing a program to manipulate LaTeX and I'd like to have access to some standard terminology. For example, is there a standard name for a string of the form `\abcd`, or `\textbf{...}` vs `{\bf ...}` (in terms of the syntactical structure, not what the actually do)? Names for arguments in square brackets vs. the curly brackets (I've taken to calling them 'options' and 'parameters' but I have no idea if this is correct)? Does the `\documentclass{}` statment have a special name? That sort of thing.

I know that there is no context-free-grammar but I would like to find something that has a hierarchical naming convention for parts of LaTeX files, as well as some naming convention for the 'atoms' of LaTeX.

Comment: Have a look at `source2e.pdf`.

Comment: This question is *very* broad. You don't want "to read 100 pages to extract the terminology", but your requests seems to ask for reference manuals (which aren't always a short read). Specific to your question at hand, `\abcd`, `\textbf` and `\bf` are called *control sequences*, but are informally referred to as *macros*. `\abcd` is a parameter-less macro, while `\textbf` takes one *mandatory argument* (as opposed to the *optional* kind in square brackets). `\bf` is also sometimes referred to as a *switch* since it provides font-related changes.

Comment: As a start for a reference, read [The TeX Book](http://www.ctex.org/documents/shredder/src/texbook.pdf) and [TeX by Topic](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/plain/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf) for some in-depth discussions and terminology. If this seems a bit much, read [TeX for the Impatient](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/plain/impatient/book.pdf).

Comment: `\bf` is also obsolete for current LaTeX. Some classes define it for compatibility reason, though.

Comment: What the question is lacking so far, is the understanding between the difference of LaTeX and TeX.

Comment: @Werner: I agree, it's a broad question. I know many languages have a specification that have a condensed grammar, I guess that's what I'm looking for BUT what you mentioned above is perfect.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Thanks, just downloaded it. The point of the \bf was to illustrate a syntactical construct rather than to be compiled.

Comment: For the LaTeX kernel as a user I'd say Lamport's _LaTeX: A Document Preparation System_ is the _definitive_ guide, but the moment you add packages that's not longer the case ...